# Is there an adjective for "something that tends to be forgotten easily"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

When a learner does not practice a language for a while the language tends to be forgotten.

What is the adjective to describe this characteristic of learning a language or any other subject?

"This subject is ..."
Or
"Language is ..."

Note - To me, when something is "forgettable", you kind of want to forget it because it is ,maybe, not worth it to be remembered, but in the case of language and other subjects of study, I though it might be something different.

Comment: *forgettable*....

Comment: @Drew To me, when something is "forgettable", you kind of want to forget it because it is ,maybe, not worth it to be remembered, but in the case of language and other subjects of study, I though it might be something different!

Comment: @Sharaman That comment should be part of the question: your impression of the word and what you *actually* want to convey is important. For what it's worth, I don't think English has a single word for this: such a language is described as ***easily forgotten.***

Comment: Were it not for the [single-word-request] tag, I'd recommend the phrase "use it or lose it."

Answer (score 3):

[forgettable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forgettable) (MWD)

> likely to be forgotten : not worth remembering

Comment: No cigar. A language is certainly worth remembering.

Comment: That's subjective. In any case, I'm looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Check. ..........

Answer (score 3):

Without constant practice, one's knowledge of a language, any language, would tend to be fugacious ... ephemeral ... evanescent ... fleeting ... transitory.

**fugacious**:

fleeting, transitory

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fugacious

**ephemeral**:

lasting a very short time

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ephemeral?s=t

**evanescent**:

vanishing, fading away, fleeting

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/evanescent

**transitory**:

lasting only a short time

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/transitory?s=t

**fleeting**:

passing quickly, vanishing swiftly

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fleeting?s=t

Comment: TIL _fugacious_.  Comes from the same root as _fugitive_ and _refuge_.

Comment: While not wrong, the adjectives you suggest apply to the *knowledge* of something (e.g. language), and not to the thing itself.

Answer (score 2):

Any subject or language itself is not **diminishable** but the knowledge of the subject or language surely is.

See **diminish**, defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/diminish) as

> make or become less.

Or perhaps

> Knowledge is subject to **atrophy**.

See **atrophy** defined by [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/atrophy) as

> Gradual decline in effectiveness or vigour due to underuse or neglect.